# How to control \parskip space through the document?

Tags: line-spacing, parskip

I just discovered the I shoudn't be using `\\` as paragraphe separator, so I replaced it with `\par`. 
I wanted also a slight space between paragraphes so I set `\setlength{\parskip}{1em}` and it's lovely but Latex put an extra space litteraly everywhere! So my table of contents is spread through 5 pages, and what is worst my `\expex` exemples are also very wide.

How can I control it? Is there a command that allows me to have this blank space in texte only?

Comment: For separation of paragraph is not necessary to use `\par` on the end of paragraph. It is sufficient to put blank line between them. For more sophisticated control of `parskip` see link which provide Alan Munn.

Comment: A blank line is enough to separate paragraphs. A value of `\parskip=1em` is huge, and it should be a `rubber length` with a `plus` and a `minus` part. Furthermore, there is a side-effect on the `list environments` and the `table of contents`, so you should either load the `parskip` package, or use one of the `komascript` classes.

Comment: I never had problems with my lists, just the table of contents and the exemples were affected. Any way, I went through the other question again, and it seems to be working now. Thanks a lot and sorry for duplicate.. :)